# i is not defined, referencing value in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

**I have two functions:**

- `printData()` has a for loop of numbers from one through twenty and then uses the value of i to grab the related data about each school
- `pickSubject()` should display the text related to a specific subject: english, math, science or social studies on button click

## Problem

Trying to reference the value of `i` in the first function, but I'm getting the error in the console `i is not defined` because of its scope. How do I reference `i`?

## scripts.js

```
$(function(){

    function printData() {
        // Iterate over all the school names
        for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);

            // Schools
            var schoolName = $(".school__name").eq(i).html(schools[i].name); // Name
            var schoolDistrict = $(".school__district").eq(i).html(schools[i].district); // District
            // var schoolCrest = // $(".school__image").attr("src", schools[i].crest) // Crest

            // Default
            var percentEnglish = $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentEnglish); // English
        }
    }

    function pickSubject() {
        $(".btn").click(function(){
            $(".btn").removeClass("is-selected");
            $(this).addClass("is-selected");

            // Button behavior
            if ($(this).hasClass("btn-english")) {
                $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentEnglish);
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-math")) {
                var percentMath = $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentMath); // Math
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-science")) {
                var percentScience = $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentScience); // Science
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-social")) {
                var percentSocial = $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentSocial); // Social Science
            }
        });
    }

    printData();
    pickSubject();

});
```

## index.html

```
<div class="widget high-school">
    <div class="widget__info">
        <p class="widget__category">High school</p>
        <p class="widget__title">Missouri Assessment Program standouts</p>
    </div>

    <div class="widget__buttons">
        <p class="widget__rank">Rank by:</p>
        <button class="btn btn-english is-selected">English</button>
        <button class="btn btn-math">Math</button>
        <button class="btn btn-science">Science</button>
        <button class="btn btn-social">Social Studies</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="schools">
            <div class="school" data-id="1">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="5">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="7">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="8">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="9">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="10">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="11">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="13">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="14">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="15">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="16">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="17">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="18">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="19">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->

            <div class="school" data-id="20">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
                <div class="school__details">
                    <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
                    <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
                </div>
                <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
            </div> <!-- school -->
        </div><!-- schools -->
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use a global variable, but I'm kind of against it since it's just used for index accessing. Consider using both code blocks in the same loop.

Comment: Don't use a global variable. That's just going to make matters worse

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your trying to do from the code posted

Comment: `How do I reference i` I think this is the wrong question to ask. I believe your logic will need to be restructured because you _really_ shouldn't be in this situation.

Comment: yes this what @vlaz said

Comment: @Liam to add to `do not use a global` it's not even going to help at all, since there is no overlap between the two functions. Even if `i` were to be global, it would never be dynamic and it would always be the last number from that loop.

Comment: @vlaz Agreed on the structure needing some work.

Comment: Tl;Dr take a step back and start again you've wondered down a one way street here

Comment: Can people recommend some structural changes to my code in snippets then? @DrewKennedy

Comment: @vlaz Do you have any structural changes / code snippet that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of accessing parameters in multiple functions:

1.pass it:

```
function a(){
var i;
b(i);//pass it
}
```

2.make it global for both:

```
var i;
function a(){}
function b(){}
```

Comment: I was tempted to say something along these lines, but this is far too simplistic and misses the point of what he's trying to achieve here.

Comment: Both approaches won't work in this case because the second function is not called inside the first one - they are called sequentially. So, the logic, design, control flow, and probably some of the assumptions around that code need to be changed.

Comment: @Jonas w Do you have any suggestions for how to alter my code so that I could pass `i` into the function instead of setting a global variable

Comment: @Andrew Nguyen : as i was set to schools.length, you can simply use schools.length instead of i in your pick subject...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to update **all** values of percentages on click. This can be done with the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$(".school__percentage").each(function(i) {
  $(this).html(schools[i][key]);
});
```

Where `key` is `"percentEnglish"`, `"percentSocial"`, etc.

Full example:

```js
// placeholder values
var schools = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  schools.push({
  name: 'Name ' + i,
  district: 'District ' + i,
  percentEnglish: 1 * i,
  percentMath: 10 * i,
  percentScience: 100 * i,
  percentSocial: 1000 * i
});
}

$(function() {

  function printData() {
    // Iterate over all the school names
    for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);

      // Schools
      var schoolName = $(".school__name").eq(i).html(schools[i].name); // Name
      var schoolDistrict = $(".school__district").eq(i).html(schools[i].district); // District
      // var schoolCrest = // $(".school__image").attr("src", schools[i].crest) // Crest

      // Default
      var percentEnglish = $(".school__percentage").eq(i).html(schools[i].percentEnglish); // English
    }
  }

  function pickSubject() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
      $(".btn").removeClass("is-selected");
      $(this).addClass("is-selected");
      var key;
      // Button behavior
      if ($(this).hasClass("btn-english")) {
        key = 'percentEnglish';
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-math")) {
        key = 'percentMath'; // Math
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-science")) {
        key = 'percentScience'; // Science
      } else if ($(this).hasClass("btn-social")) {
        key = 'percentSocial'; // Social Science
      }
      $(".school__percentage").each(function(i) {
        $(this).html(schools[i][key]);
      });
    });
  }

  printData();
  pickSubject();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget high-school">
  <div class="widget__info">
    <p class="widget__category">High school</p>
    <p class="widget__title">Missouri Assessment Program standouts</p>
  </div>

  <div class="widget__buttons">
    <p class="widget__rank">Rank by:</p>
    <button class="btn btn-english is-selected">English</button>
    <button class="btn btn-math">Math</button>
    <button class="btn btn-science">Science</button>
    <button class="btn btn-social">Social Studies</button>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="schools">
      <div class="school" data-id="1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="8">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="9">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="10">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="11">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="12">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="13">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="14">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="15">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="16">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="17">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="18">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="19">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->

      <div class="school" data-id="20">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" class="school__image">
        <div class="school__details">
          <div class="school__name">tk-name</div>
          <div class="school__district">tk-district</div>
        </div>
        <div class="school__percentage">-%</div>
      </div>
      <!-- school -->
    </div>
    <!-- schools -->
  </div>
```

Comment: This was very close